# Create pkg file in lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, pkg-file

I'm quite new to AWS S3 and Lambda. Using nodejs 4.3 with Lambda is it possible to pull in multiple files from an S3 bucket and compile them into a single osx flat package(.pkg)?

Comment: Can you give more details? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a unique mac installer pkg from files in an S3. The package has to be created from existing files in the S3, not uploaded as a pkg from a mac. Thanks @dashmug

Comment: Is it possible to do that on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a library to do it within Lambda's 300 second hard timeout, sure.